# Transparence of image not working on shiny

Tags: r, image, shiny

I have a png image with a transparent background but when it is displayed with shiny, the background become white and the image have more width than the original.

The image :

[image]

What it looks like in shiny :

[image]

Part of the shiny code with the image:

```
title <- tags$a(tags$img(src="shield.png", height='30', width='50'), 'League of Squads', style = "color: white;")
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = title,titleWidth = 250),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded your picture, it has 392x390px. You have to scale it down accordingly (30x30, not 30x50). Otherwise it will look scretched.

Why the image has white background? I can not tell you, there are two possible options:
1. You converted it wrong.
2. It is placed inside a `div` with white background.

In my own code, it worked fine.

```
   ## app.R ##

title <- tags$a(tags$img(src="shield.png", height='30', width='30'), 'League of Squads', style = "color: white;")

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = title,titleWidth = 250),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, now it works well, the white background disappeared. It seems it kept the previous image even if I change it for the one without background. But thanks for your answer !